# How can find out the broadcast intent actions of other apps?

Tags: android

I'm trying to read audio meta data that is broadcast by other apps. There is no standard for broadcasting meta data, but a common way is to send one with an action that ends with .metachanged and extras that list artist, album, etc.

How can I determine what broadcasts are coming from various other apps?  If I could just filter all broadcasts, then I could read through them and be able to tell which apps are broadcasting their meta data, and how it's formatted.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I determine what broadcasts are coming from various other apps?

You ask the developers of those apps what broadcasts they send out that they support. If you are expecting to be able to discover this programmatically, that is not possible, sorry.

Now, if they happen to listen to their own broadcasts, you may see that in the apps' manifests (if they are not using `registerReceiver()`. As a developer, you can examine this via apps like [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&feature=nav_result).
But if this is not part of some documented and supported API by those music apps, then when those music apps change their broadcasts, your app will break.